# appending to a list in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, combinations

I wrote the following recursive program which finds the combination of numbers which can be added to make the target value:

```
arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5]
target = 8

def comb_sum(arr, current_index, target, result, ans):
    if target == 0:
        print result
        ans.append(result)
        return 0
    if target < 0:
        return 1
    if current_index == len(arr):
        return 1

    result.append(arr[current_index])
    comb_sum(arr, current_index+1, target - arr[current_index], result, ans)
    result.pop()

    comb_sum(arr, current_index+1, target, result, ans)
    return ans



print comb_sum(arr, 0, target, [], [])
```

Since I am using arr.append() to append the `result`, I expected the correct output.

Even though the program is correct, I am unable to add a list `result` to the `ans`.

What's wrong?

I am expecting this output:

`[[1, 2, 2, 3],
[1, 2, 5],
[1, 2, 5],
[3, 5]]`

But instead I get this output:

`[[], [], [], []]`

Comment: What is your expecting output ?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: @yask are you using python 2.7?

Comment: Yea, https://ideone.com/Ro88Fs

Comment: @yask you only want the numbers but not the empty list right?

Comment: Unrelated, but are you aware that your method returns `true`(ish) if no result is found, and `false`(ish) if a result is found? Also, you are kind of inconsistent _what_ is returned: The result, or whether a result was found.

Comment: Yea, but since i am not using a conditional statement with `ans` variable, or with what the function returns, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: By that reasoning, it would be okay to return just anything. If you don't intend to use what's returned, don't return anything, but _if_ you return something, make it meaningful.

Comment: I am returning `ans` which is(should be) the correct ans of the problem I am solving: `program which finds the combination of numbers which can be added to make the target value:`

Comment: Yes, you return `ans`, but sometimes you also return `1` or `0`, which makes it inconsistent.

Comment: Ah! Gotya! Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
import copy
arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5]
target = 8
def comb_sum(arr, current_index, target, result, ans):

if target == 0:
    print result
    ans.append(copy.deepcopy(result) )
    return 0
if target < 0:
    return 1
if current_index == len(arr):
    return 1

result.append(arr[current_index])
comb_sum(arr, current_index+1, target - arr[current_index], result, ans)
result.pop()

comb_sum(arr, current_index+1, target, result, ans)
return ans

print comb_sum(arr, 0, target, [], [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the result list and pass like below

```
comb_sum(arr, current_index+1, target - arr[current_index], result[:], ans)
```

There is only one copy of result flowing through the program. So whenever `result` changes, it also reflects in `ans`. That's why copying it breaks the chain and gives you the correct result

Comment: It works, but I don't understand the concept. 
If you make a function which appends a value to a list , it works like a pass by reference function. Since I am able to print the correct output in the result variable, why does't it append to the `ans` variable ?

Comment: It's really good you are answering very soon. Please say why ? A answer with no explanation is also useless.

Comment: The logic behind  this that I can think of is that, perhaps the ans is appending the reference of `result`. sine `result` later changes to `''` , it shows the output as [[],[],[],[]]`